# java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String infix to postfix

Tags: java, string, floating-point

I have problem concerning evaluating postfix expression using stack

```
for(int i=0;i<postfix.length;i++){
  System.out.println("iteration:"+(i+1));
  if(postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("+") || postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-") 
      || postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("*") || postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("/") ) {
    num1 = Float.parseFloat((String)out.pop());
    System.out.println("pop:"+num1);
    num2 = Float.parseFloat((String)out.pop());
    System.out.println("pop:"+num2);
    if(postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("+")) { 
      temp = num2+num1; 
      out.push(temp);
      System.out.println("push:"+temp);
      }
    else if(postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {   
      temp = num2-num1;   
      out.push((""+temp));
      System.out.println("push:"+temp);
      }
    else if(postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {   
      temp = num2*num1;   
      out.push((""+temp));
      System.out.println("push:"+temp);
      }
    else if(postfix[i].equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
      temp = num2/num1;
      out.push((""+temp));
      System.out.println("push:"+temp);
      }
  }
  else{
    System.out.println("push:"+postfix[i]);
    out.push(postfix[i]);
  }
}
```

the code works well if i only do operation among two numbers e.g "2 4 +"
but when it becomes like "2 4 + 5 +" the error suddenly appears.. i even put markers.. the prints there to check the flow of my code ..thanks
any help?

Comment: I would store `Double` on the stack rather than use `String` or `Float`

Comment: "the error suddenly appears" what error appears where?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey accrding to netbeans. error appears on line 97 which the start of the line:     num2 = Float.parseFloat((String)out.pop());
    System.out.println("pop:"+num2);
the error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: If you really must convert Float/Double values to strings, don't use `"" + temp`; use `String.valueOf(temp)`. The first approach uses an implicit StringBuilder to do the concatenation.

Comment: well. will it really matter what type i put into stack? i mean. once i pop it out again it becomes an object type right? but the again i still get error if two or ore operands.. i get the error after it solves the first operation. pushes the result of that into stack.. then pushes the new operand.. pops when the second operator shows up. then stops the execution there. whatever operand i choose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one line `out.push(temp);` which is pushing a Float instead fo a String.

I suggest you use

```
Stack<Double> out = new Stack<Double>();
```

with

```
double num1 = out.pop();
```

and

```
out.push(num2 + num1);
```

and

```
out.push(Double.parseDouble(postfix[i]));
```

As Stack is a legacy class, a better choice would be a Deque, but I assume you don't need to worry about changing it for this project.